# How to check a text file in powershell for a range of values

Tags: powershell, parsing

I'm hoping someone can help. I'm not a programmer by any stretch , but a storage administrator and we've been told by our bosses in their wisdom that we have to come up with an automation script in powershell each. So I thought , LUN creation. I've installed the hitachi cmdlets to get free lun IDs from the storage and its either XML or text , so

```
LogicalUnitId    ResourceGroupId

0                   0
1                   0
2                   0
3                   0
```

or

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <ArrayOfFreeLogicalUnitOperationResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <FreeLogicalUnitOperationResult>
       <LogicalUnitId>0</LogicalUnitId>
        <ResourceGroupId>0</ResourceGroupId>
      </FreeLogicalUnitOperationResult>
      <FreeLogicalUnitOperationResult>
        <LogicalUnitId>1</LogicalUnitId>
        <ResourceGroupId>0</ResourceGroupId>
      </FreeLogicalUnitOperationResult>
```

now depending on what is required there is a specific range we need to use
eg

ESX5F in the range 8192 - 8447
ESX5G un the range 16640 - 16895

so say I need 3 ESX5F and 2 ESX5G how do I read the generated txt/xml for the next available IDs in those ranges?
TIA !!

Comment: Getting the hang of the formatting , the test file should read

````
LogicalUnitId ResourceGroupId
0                      0
1                      0
1                      0
````

Comment: Is something missing from your post? How do you expect to find a number in the range `8192-8447` in a document only containing numbers `0` through `3`?

Comment: what delimiter does the txt File use? Could it be interpreted as CSV with whitespace or tab as delimiter?

Comment: Your first sample is not a text output of the cmdlet. It's a collection (object[]). Something like ```[linq.enumerable]::Intersect([int[]](Get-FreeLu).LogicalUnitId, [int[]](8192..8447))``` should return LUN Ids in given range. But can't verify because I can't use that cmdlet.

Comment: Apologies, a novice at all this , I'm obviously not explaining myself well enough. the two sections are examples of the get-freelu output either in text format or xml format . How do I attach files? I can add the actual output then

Comment: @sanation99 Did you test my code snippet of my last comment? Because according to the documentation about Get-FreeLU (https://knowledge.hitachivantara.com/@api/deki/files/90793/Infrastructure_Adapter_for_Microsoft_Windows_PowerShell_v01_3_0_Users_Guide_MK-92ADPTR132-04.pdf?revision=1&usg=AOvVaw2mr31cT1NkZi64qwHbzHVj ; page 135/136) it returns a collection of objects, not just text. Your PowerShell console just represents it as text, but that's normal PowerShell behavior. Please test my code and tell us what it returns